# Cannot find placeholder inside repeater in code behind item data bound event

Tags: repeater, sitecore, placeholder

I have
    
inside repeater
when i tried to find above placeholder in code behind Item databound event it throws null
I tried following code for it.

```
Placeholder plcHolderVideo = e.Item.FindControl("plcHolderVideo") as Placeholder;
```

Comment: I got the answer actually the placeholder is conflicting with    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Placeholder
and 
Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Placeholder.

Thanks
-Vaibhav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer actually the placeholder is conflicting with    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Placeholder
and Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Placeholder.